# Customizing checkbox/radio labels in HTML format

Tags: vue-formulate

Using the `options` attribute when setting up an array of `checkbox` and/or `radio` elements, how can one customize the label in HTML format for each radio/checkbox? For example, I want to style the Date/Time with break returns -- see output example below:

```
[ ] Tuesday, Jan 1
    5:00pm to 7:30pm
[ ] Wednesday, Jan 2
    6:00am to 8:00am
[ ] Friday, Jan 4
    1:00pm to 3:30pm
```

Here's the vue code:

```html
<FormulateInput 
  type="checkbox"
  label="Select dates that applies"
  :options="options"
  v-model="dates"
  >
```

Comment: Show you current code running. It's hard to understand whats going on

Answer (score 2):

Vue Formulate, by default, does not use `v-html` for labels (for security reasons). However, you can choose to implement your own `slotComponent` for labels that does.

```js
import VueFormulate from '@braid/vue-formulate'
import MyLabel from './MyLabel.vue'


Vue.component('MyLabel', MyLabel)

Vue.use(VueFormulate, {
  slotComponents: {
    label: 'MyLabel'
  }
})
```

```
// MyLabel.vue
<template>
<label
  class="context.classes.label"
  for="context.id"
  v-html="context.label"
/>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  props: {
    context: {
      type: Object,
      required: true
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

Then in your options objects, you would be able to use HTML strings as the keys:

```js
const dates = [
  { label: 'Tuesday, Jan 1<br>5:00pm to 7:30pm': value: '01-01-2020' }
  { label: 'Wednesday, Jan 2<br>6:00am to 8:00am': value: '01-02-2020' }
]
```